# Cell dimensions of a grid isn't consistent when scaling the content inside it

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, scaling

I have a grid contain a Lottie animation (named  as "animationView") in the cell of the first row and column.

During run time, when the user press the animation, I scale It to a new size:

```
await animationView.ScaleTo(0.333);
```

The problem is that the dimensions of the cell isn't change with it, and as a result there is a lot of space left between the animation and the cell border.

Unfortunately, setting the cell row and column definition to AUTO, isn't help...

I dedicated a lot of time trying to solve it, with out any success.

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you use `animationView.ScaleTo();` to change the animationView, actually, it is just magnified per pixel like following GIF.

[image]

It will not change the Gird's width or height. If you want to adjust the `Gird` dynamically when scale animationView to a new size , you should set the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` of the animationView dynamically like following screenshot.

In the end, my workaround:set to one third of the original `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` when you click the animationView.And do not forget to set `olumnDefinition Width="Auto"` and `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />`

[image]

Hope above workaround is helpful.

Comment: @MrSonic Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.